# Neo4j APOC reliable export/import to file format?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

APOC procedures support the following export/import formats: ([export](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/export/), [import](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/import/))

- CSV
- JSON
- Cypher script
- Graphml
- Gephi

From what I've tried using csv and cypher script is very slow compared to graphml, thus I haven't followed up on these.

Using graphml is fast but it seems that some information gets lost between export and import (field types
like integers suddenly become strings even though `useTypes` is set to `true` on export). It is also not feasible to track changes with `git` (when exporting/importing schema and structural nodes only, no data) because when `exporting -> wiping database -> importing (from first export) -> exporting again` changes the order of the exported data completely between the first export and second export file.

JSON has an option to select between four formats: `JSON_LINES (default)`, `ARRAY_JSON`, `JSON`, `JSON_ID_AS_KEYS`

Is JSON as fast as graphml and a typesafe format? Are any of the JSON format options objectively better than others?

Comment: if you do exporting -> wiping database -> importing (from first export) -> exporting again, why don't you just do a database dump?

Comment: @TomažBratanič neo4j needs to be completely stopped in order for a database dump (at least with version 3) to happen so I would need to shut down the container, run a temporary neo4j command and then start the database again.

Comment: Also, database dumps are not git diff-able because they are binary.

Comment: in 3.5/4.X neo4jadmin dump/backup can be done online, only restore/load need to be offline...